# How to signal YamlDotNet to serialize byte[] as !!binary type in .NET 5 (previous answer is not working)

Tags: c#, .net-5, yamldotnet

In question [YamlDotNet !!binary type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619841/yamldotnet-binary-type) the answer provided by Antoine Aubry and the example in [A fully working example can be tried here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1plIcc) do not work with `Version="11.2.1"`.

Is there any way to add a decorator in object properties or an alternative procedure like the former referenced?.

Our trouble is that byte array properties `byte[]` serialize in a very long (too many lines) file, and base64 encoding will improve that substantially.

Answer (score 0):

We inspect the source repository at [GitHub](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet) to find out the new way to do it.

And found in the release log the `SerializerBuilder` and `DeserializerBuilder`, so we make changes in the example referenced above ([A fully working example can be tried here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1plIcc)) and include a fully running project example, but the core changes are these:

##### To serialize

change:

```
var serializer = new Serializer();
serializer.RegisterTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter());
```

for:

```
var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
  .WithTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter())
  .Build();
```

##### To deserialize

change:

```
var deserializer = new Deserializer();
deserializer.RegisterTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:binary", typeof(byte[]));
deserializer.RegisterTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter());
```

for:

```
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
  .WithTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter())
  .WithTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:binary", typeof(byte[]))
  .Build();
```

##### Full demo example

Main program `Program.cs` (using a `Demo.cs` class for testing)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

namespace SerializeByteArrayAsBinary
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var demoToSerialize = new Demo { Data = new byte[40] };

      // Serialization
      var serializer = new SerializerBuilder()
        .WithTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter())
        .Build();
      var demoSerialized = serializer.Serialize(demoToSerialize);
      Console.WriteLine($"--- After serialization the {nameof(Demo)} object is:\n{demoSerialized}\n");

      // Deserialization
      var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
        .WithTypeConverter(new ByteArrayConverter())
        .WithTagMapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:binary", typeof(byte[]))
        .Build();
      var demoDeserialized = deserializer.Deserialize<Demo>(demoToDeserialize);
      var demoDeserializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(demoDeserialized, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
      Console.WriteLine($"--- After deserialization the {nameof(Demo)} object viewed as JSON is:\n{demoDeserializedJson}");

      // Verifications
      if (demoToSerialize.Name != demoDeserialized.Name ||
        demoToSerialize.Address != demoDeserialized.Address ||
        !demoToSerialize.Data.SequenceEqual(demoDeserialized.Data))
        throw new Exception($"Fail, {nameof(demoToSerialize)} is different from {nameof(demoDeserialized)}");

      if (demoSerialized != demoToDeserialize)
        throw new Exception($"Fail, {nameof(demoSerialized)} is different from {nameof(demoToDeserialize)}");
    }

    const string demoToDeserialize = @"Name: Jhon Doe
Address: 1200 Somewhere St
Data: !!binary AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
";

  }
}
```

Demostration class `Demo.cs`

```
using System;

namespace SerializeByteArrayAsBinary
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Demo class to demonstrate how to serialize and deserialize with YamlDotNet.
  /// </summary>
  public class Demo
  {
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Jhon Doe";
    public string Address { get; set; } = "1200 Somewhere St";
    public byte[] Data { get; set; } = Array.Empty<byte>();
  }
}
```

Original `ByteArrayConverter.cs` (untouched)

```
using System;
using YamlDotNet.Core;
using YamlDotNet.Serialization;

namespace SerializeByteArrayAsBinary
{
  public class ByteArrayConverter : IYamlTypeConverter
  {
    public bool Accepts(Type type)
    {
      return type == typeof(byte[]);
    }

    public object ReadYaml(IParser parser, Type type)
    {
      var scalar = (YamlDotNet.Core.Events.Scalar)parser.Current;
      var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(scalar.Value);
      parser.MoveNext();
      return bytes;
    }

    public void WriteYaml(IEmitter emitter, object value, Type type)
    {
      var bytes = (byte[])value;
      emitter.Emit(new YamlDotNet.Core.Events.Scalar(
          null,
          "tag:yaml.org,2002:binary",
          Convert.ToBase64String(bytes),
          ScalarStyle.Plain,
          false,
          false
      ));
    }
  }
}
```